# Activate blog hook

Tags: multisite

I want to hook a function upon activation of a blog in wordpress multisite.

I have this,

```
add_filter( 'add_signup_meta', 'custom_add_signup_meta' );

function custom_add_signup_meta ( $blogmeta = array() ) {

        $the_country = $_POST['country-origin'];
        $d_currency = $_POST['user_currency'];
        $d_zone = $_POST['state-origin'];

        $blogmeta['countries_id'] = $the_country;
        $blogmeta['default_currency'] = $d_currency;
        $blogmeta['zone_id'] = $d_zone;

    return $blogmeta;

}

add_action( 'wpmu_activate_blog', 'insert_custom_datas1', 10, 3 );

function insert_custom_datas1($blog_id, $blogmeta) {
        global $wpdb, $blogname, $blog_title, $errors, $domain, $path;
        $wp_blogs = $wpdb->base_prefix . "blogs";

        $wpdb->query("UPDATE `" . $wp_blogs . "` SET `countries_id`='".$wpdb->escape($blogmeta['countries_id'])."', `default_currency`='".$wpdb->escape($blogmeta['default_currency'])."', `zone_id`='".$wpdb->escape($blogmeta['zone_id'])."' where `blog_id` = '" . (int)$blog_id . "'");

}
```

However, its not working.. what suppose to be the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible causes I can think of:

1. The '`wpmu_activate_blog`' hook supplies 5 arguments (`$blog_id, $user_id, $password, $signup->title, $meta`), but you're only receiving 2 parameters (`$blog_id, $blogmeta`)
2. The '`wpmu_activate_blog`' hook is only triggered when a user creates a blog and not when the super adimin creates one.

Comment: Where should i hook the function for all signups?